# multer file upload hangs with express on server but not locally

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have been searching a while but not got answer please help

So I want to upload files to server, I have code

```
var upload = multer({ storage: common.storage , fileFilter : common.fileFilter,limits:{fileSize:config.maxSize} }).array('media');

upload(req, res, function (err) {

    if (err) {

        res.json({'success' : false , 'err' : err ,  msg : 'Something went wrong please try again'});
    }else{

        if(req.fileValidationError) {

            return res.end(req.fileValidationError);
        }`
```

Its some code to upload file on multer where common.storage function is as

```
'storage' : multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {

     console.log(req.pathToSaveFile)
     cb(null, 'uploads/' + req.pathToSaveFile)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     console.log('file' , file)
     cb(null, req.timestamp +'_'+ file.originalname)
  },

}),
```

after console file nothing happens, please help me in this

`

Comment: Hey, Any clues ?

Comment: In my case the internet speed was very low

Answer (score 1):

If your server is running with PM2 than its the most common error we got, because of watch here is an example for file upload with node js.

```
const multer = require('multer');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({server
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'UPLOAD_FOLDER_PATH');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:\.Z]/g, "") + file.originalname) ; // toISOString has been used to rename your file.
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('YOUR_INPUT_FIELD_NAME');
upload(req,res,function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return res.end("Error uploading file.");
  } else {
    // File uploaded successfully.
    // Do you stuff.
  }
```

**Note : There are two way to use for the following code with PM2**

1) Start PM2 server without watch. (Not recommended.)

pm2 start index.js

2) Start PM2 server with watch and ignore file upload folder.

**pm2 start index.js --watch --ignore-watch "UPLOAD_FOLDER_PATH"**

Happy coding cheers!

Comment: in my case even if I don't use pm2 it's still hang as @irfan khan mentioned

Comment: You solved it for me, Thanks after 3 yrs